# Is path traversal possible using Javas File constructor?

Tags: java, security, path-traversal

I'm building a webservice where users can upload zipfiles that get unzipped and saved to our server.

I created the following function to open a file in a specified path:

```
private File secureOpenFile(String fileName, String directorypath){
        return new File(directorypath, fileName);
}
```

But a security scan tells me that this is not safe, as it has the possibility of path traversal. Giving the arguments ("../../notsafe", "uploadfolder") would allow a malicious attacker to overwrite other files...

However, in the documentation of the File class I found the following: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)

> Otherwise the parent abstract pathname is taken to denote a directory, and the child pathname string is taken to denote either a directory or a file. If the child pathname string is absolute then it is converted into a relative pathname in a system-dependent way. If parent is the empty abstract pathname then the new File instance is created by converting child into an abstract pathname and resolving the result against a system-dependent default directory. Otherwise each pathname string is converted into an abstract pathname and the child abstract pathname is resolved against the parent.

Which I interpreted as: does not leave the parent folder. Am I correct or not? Is this code safe? And if now: what would be the best way to resolve this security issue?

Comment: Do you take any input which are in parameter from user?

Comment: Hey ProgrammerBoy. The second argument, the filename, comes from the zipfile the user uploads. I suspect the user can put anything strange in this zipfile, so I don't trust that input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

> ...the child abstract pathname is resolved against the parent.

just means the parent path is used as the *base* when resolving the child path, but if the child path contains `..`, the result will be outside of the parent.

E.g.

```
new File("/Users/example/projects/sample/target", "../pom.xml").getCanonicalFile();
```

results in `/Users/example/projects/sample/pom.xml`, thus outside of `target`.

So, in short, yes, you do need to guard against this yourself.